# list index out of range sin sentido

Tags: python, python-3.x, array, lista

Estoy haciendo un script para poder sumar algunas columnas de un archivo csv.

el código que les muestro es como saco los valores que necesito y los pongo en dos lista especificas:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

valores=[]
cliente=[]
total=[]
#cargo todo los valores que necesito
with open('G:\xxx\xxx\compra.csv') as file:
    for row in file:
        valores.append(row.strip().split(','))
file.close()
# cargare los id de clientes
with open('G:\xxx\xxx\cliente.csv') as file:
    for row in file:
        cliente.append(row.strip().split(','))
file.close()
extracData=[fila[0] for fila in cliente]
```

luego de eso comparo la lista con el array(matriz) que tengo

```
for i in range(len(valores)):
    for k in range(len(extracData)):
        if(valores[i][1]==extracData[k] and valores[i][1]!="idCliente"):
            total[k] = total[k] + int(valores[i][4])
```

he hecho el debugg que puedo y por lo que veo no debería haber error, mi código debería de comparar los valores, y los compara bien porque entra en mi condición `if`, el problema esta en que me dice:

```
total[k] = total[k] + int(valores[i][4])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

En la sección de la suma pero la k cambiar bien y la i también debería estar ok

Me pueden dar una mano con esto?

Comment: te dare una pista, len te da el valor del largo del contenido de una variable, por ej HOLA tiene un largo de 4, pero para recorrerlo tienes que comenzar desde la posicion 0 hasta la 3, si imprimes la posicion 4 te dara error de fuera de rango.

Comment: Lo se, pero revise eso y el len de ambos deberia estar bien, es mas le he hecho impresiones para ver que valores mi tiran y esta todo bien.....yo creo que el problema es el i de total

Comment: Corrijo sospeche que es la variable k la que me causa problemas, pero no tengo idea del porque

Comment: prueba cambiando los rangos a mano, o con un -1, juega un poco con las numero de rango

Comment: Ya que las variables `i` y `k` van iterando segun un `range(len(...))`, no deberían salirse de rango nunca. Por tanto conjeturo que el problema es del `[4]`. Alguno de tus elementos de la lista `valores` tiene menos de 5 elementos dentro y el intento de acceder al `[4]` te da el error. Prueba a imprimir `valores[i]` justo delante del `for k...` y así justo antes de que se produzca el error podrás ver qué fila es la que tiene menos de 5 elementos.

Answer (score 2):

Parece que el problema esta en la lista vacía «total». Nunca le agregaste ningún contenido a tu lista «total», sin embargo, en la parte de la suma intentas acceder con «total[k]» a un elemento que no existe

Comment: Tienes razón. El OP importó `defaultdict`, lo cual sugiere que en pretendia escribir `total = defaultdict(int)`. Probablemente se le pasó. Te doy un +1.

Answer (score 0):

Como dijo Atake72, no tienes inicializada la lista `total`, que es la causa del error.

Adicionalmente te estas complicando la vida de tal manera que es mejor reescribirlo por completo.

Revisando el código, deduzco que `compra.csv` tiene esta estructura:

```
numero, cliente, valor1, valor2, valor3, valor4
1,jaime2000,10,20,30,40
2,s_olmos,11,21,31,41
3,jaime2000,10,20,30,40
```

También deduzco que el resultado deseado es la acumular las compras por cliente. Para eso no necesito leer el archivo `clientes.csv`, ya que el código de cliente viene en la compra. Eliminare esa parte.

Estas leyendo mal el archivo. Si un CSV, tienes que leerlo con un lector como `csv.reader`. Si usas `split(',')` vas a tener problema si alguna cadena incluye una coma dentro de ellas.

También tienes que saltarte la primera línea de archivo, pues trae los nombres de las columnas, no los datos de una compra.

No necesitas leer todo el archivo de compras a memoria; puedes ir procesando y acumulando de inmediato. El diccionario `total` estara indexado por código de cliente.

Tampoco necesitas hacer `close` del archivo; el `with` lo cierra automáticamente al salir del bloque.

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

total= defaultdict(int)

with open('compra.csv') as file:
    file.readline()
    csvFile = csv.reader(file)
    for row in csvFile:
        total[row[1]] += int(row[4])

for k, v in total.items():
    print(k, v)
```

produce

```
jaime2000 60
s_olmos 31
```